# TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined when I call a method from an Imported Class [TypeScript]

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, service, controller

After debugging this for few hours, I couldn't find anything online either..

I have a controller that call a service method to get data back:

**Route: routes/inspections.ts**

```
import {Request, Response} from "express";
import { InspectionsController } from "../controllers";

export class Routes {

    public inspectionsController: InspectionsController = new InspectionsController()
    public  routes(app): void {


        // Inspection detail
        app.route('/data/inspections/:inspectionId')
        // get specific inspection
            .get(this.inspectionsController.getInspectionByID)

        // Inspection detail
        app.route('/data/inspections')
        // get specific inspection
            .get(this.inspectionsController.getInspections)

    }
}
```

**Controller: controllers/inspections.ts**

```
    import { Request, Response } from 'express';
    import { InspectionsService } from '../services/inspections';

    export class InspectionsController {
        public inspectionsService: InspectionsService = new InspectionsService();
        public async getInspections (req: Request, res: Response) {
            try {
                const response = await this.inspectionsService.getInspections();
                res.json(response);
            }catch (e) {
                console.log(e.toString())
            }
        }

        public getInspectionByID (req: Request, res: Response) {
            res.json('You reached getInspectionByID in the controller Wohoooo!');
        }
}
```

**Service: services/inspections.ts**

```
    export class InspectionsService {
     public  async getInspections(){
         return 'You reached getInspections in the service Wohoooo!';
    }
}
```

My problem is that my program reach only the controller level, and does not reach the service. 
I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'inspectionsService' of undefined
```

Many thanks in advance guys, any help is truly appreciated!

Comment: Why is there a trailing `}` in your `inspections.ts` file ? That last `}` in `inspections.ts` might be causing some problems?

Comment: Hi @Soufiane how can I help you?

Comment: Hi @Dacre Denny, thanks for your quick answer bud' I just deleted some stuff while pasting the code here that's why, but in my IDE I don't have any extra } :/

Comment: Hi @Soufiane, I can't see anything unusual. Why don't you return a promise while calling await?

Comment: Hi @Abhishek , thank you so much for your prompt answer, I did exactly what you suggested but I still have the same error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'inspectionsService' of undefined
That is very weird :/

Comment: @Soufiane, I edited my post, just included in constructor.

Comment: @Abhishek : Thank you so much man, you rock!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue is possibly relating to the context that `inspectionsController.getInspections` is invoked from in your router.

Perhaps you could make the following changes to your router, to ensure that `getInspections` is called from the context of your `Routes` instance - do these changes work for you?

```
export class Routes {

    public inspectionsController: InspectionsController = new InspectionsController()
    public  routes(app): void {


        // Inspection detail
        app.route('/data/inspections/:inspectionId')
        // get specific inspection
            .get(this.inspectionsController.getInspectionByID)

        // Inspection detail
        app.route('/data/inspections')
        // get specific inspection
        .get((req: Request, res: Response) => {

          // UPDATE: Move the invocation of getInspections() into an arrow function
          // so that the "this" context is that of the Routes instance
          this.inspectionsController.getInspections(req, res)
        })

    }
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, thank you so much bud', much appreciated :D

Comment: Hey you're welcome! Glad I could help - all the best with your project :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your controller,

constructor(private inspectionsService: InspectionsService) {}

```js
public getInspections(){
  return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('You reached getInspections in the service Wohoooo!');
      }, 2000);
  });
}
```